# Everything that happens inside an environment depends on a specific target -- is that possible?

Tags: scons

Let's say I have two `SConscript`s:

```
SConstruct
  SConscript a
  SConscript b
```

`SConscript a` generates a `pkg-config` file (for something foreign which has none). I have an alias for this (substitution, installing etc.), `pkg_alias`. `SConscript b` invokes `env.ParseConfig(...)` and builds `app`, and therefore it's important that the file already was generated (otherwise `pkg-config` would complain).

So what I need is a dependency like this: `app` -> `parse` -> `pkg_alias`.

Is it possible to express this?

Like `subdir_env.Depends(subdir_env, 'pkg_alias')` when `subdir_env` is the one that attempts to `ParseConfig`.

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming this

> app -> parse -> pkg_alias

means that app depends on parse, and parse depends on pkg_alias.

If you are calling `pkg-config` via the Command() builder, then SCons will create a target for it that can be used for dependencies. The problem is that I dont think you can make ParseConfig() depend on the `pkg-config` target, since ParseConfig() is executed before any targets are built. Actually the SConstruct and all SConscript's are evaluated before building any targets.

Instead, you could call `pkg-config` directly via Python without using the Command() builder, then call ParseConfig() all before building the targets. Then the app will be built according to what is in the env.

Just in case, you can get everything in the same env as follows:

Invoke the SConscript's with the `SConscript()` function. When you do this, you can create an Environment in the SConstruct and export it to the SConscripts as follows:

SConstruct

```
env = Environment()
SConscript('suba/SConscript', exports='env', duplicate=0)
SConscript('subb/SConscript', exports='env', duplicate=0)
```

suba/Sconscript

```
Import('env')
```

Then, anything you do in any of the scripts will be done on the same environment.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem: `ParseConfig` is executed before the first target is built, and since building the file `pkg-config` depends on *is* a target, this will fail. I think I try your recommendation to make this a target via the `Command` builder, but I'm not sure how to modify the environment within this. I will try tomorrow.